# Docker compose file version compatibility error

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I have docker engine with version 20.10.5

```
Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88
```

and docker-compose version 1.23.2

```
docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01
```

on ubuntu version 20.04

```
Linux ed 5.4.0-66-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 27 22:54:38 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When i try to use docker-compose command on a file with version 3.8 it gives error.

```
ERROR: Version in "./jenkins.docker-compose.yml" is unsupported. You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a supported version (e.g "2.2" or "3.3") and place your service definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
```

If i change to version 3.7 it works. Docker documentation mentions version 3.8 should work with docker engine 19.03.0+

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  jenkins:
    build: .  
    image: jenkins:lts
    container_name: jenkins
    privileged: true
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "50000:50000"
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - ed 
    volumes:
      - jenkins-log:/var/log/jenkins
      - jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./downloads:/var/jenkins_home/downloads
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=jenkins.ed.tech
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=8080
        #- SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-agent
volumes:
  jenkins-data:
  jenkins-log:
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: ed
```

What i am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version of `docker-compose` doesn't support compose version 3.8. You'll need to update to at least `docker-compose` version 1.25.5: https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.25.5

Comment: Thank you. I could not see in official compatibility document. I think this info should be part of documentaion at https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/